# Amadeus Self-Service APIs Flight order create issue / Itinerary requested is not found

Tags: api, amadeus

I am using the self-service API to make a flight order and I get below error, I am testing on Amadeus API testing tool. Can't seem to understand the issue, as the request is freshly fetched from the flight search API

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 400,
      "code": 4926,
      "title": "INVALID DATA RECEIVED",
      "detail": "Itinerary requested is not found"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is raised when the JSON body of Flight Create Orders call is not correctly built.

The usual flow to build the request should be as follows:

1. Call Flight Offers Search to get the list of flight offers.
2. Send a new request of type "flight-offers-pricing" to Flight Offers Price, using the list of flight offers that you are interested in, from the previous call.
3. Send a new request of type "flight-order" to Flight Create Orders, taking the output of Flight Offer Price and adding "travelers" section.

You can find detailed information in the [booking engine tutorial](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/tutorial-booking-engine-amadeus-flight-booking-api) from the blog.